# getting this error while using volley in android E/Volley: [3355] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 422

Tags: android, android-volley

getting this error while using access token to register in an app with username and password using volley. Got access token but not able to get the response after passing the token.

```
  private void getRegisterToken() {
    final String grant_type = ApiConstants.CLIENT_GRANT_TYPE;
    final String client_id = ApiConstants.CLIENT_ID;
    final String client_secret = ApiConstants.CLIENT_SECRET;


    StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,  API_BASE_URL_TOKEN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Response:%n %s", response);
                    if (pDialog != null)
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        if (UtilValidate.isNotNull(response)) {
                            JSONObject responseJSONObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (responseJSONObject.has(ApiConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
                                String access_token = Utils.getJSONString(responseJSONObject, ApiConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN);

                                registerDetails(access_token);
                                //  getUserDetails(access_token);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException ignored) {
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                    if (UtilValidate.isNotNull(networkResponse)) {
                        if (pDialog != null)
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        if (pDialog != null)
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        Snackbar.make(login_linear_register, getString(R.string.chk_credentials), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        /*    params.put(KEY_USERNAME, "");
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, inputusername);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, inputpassword);
         */
            params.put(KEY_GRANT_TYPE, grant_type);
            params.put(KEY_CLIENT_ID, client_id);
            params.put(KEY_CLIENT_SECRET, client_secret);
            return params;
        }

    };
    TwistedAppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest1);
}

//Get Details of logged user


private void registerDetails(final String access_token) {

  //        final String grant_type = ApiConstants.CLIENT_GRANT_TYPE;
 //        final String client_id = ApiConstants.CLIENT_ID;
//        final String client_secret = ApiConstants.CLIENT_SECRET;
      StringRequest stringRequest = new    StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_USER,

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Response:%n %s", response);
                    if (pDialog != null)
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        if (UtilValidate.isNotNull(response)) {
                            if (pDialog != null)
                                pDialog.dismiss();

                            Intent intent = new   Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }
                    } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    NetworkResponse networkResponse =  error.networkResponse;

                    if (UtilValidate.isNotNull(networkResponse)) {


                        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,       LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        if (pDialog != null)
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        Snackbar.make(login_linear_register,   getString(R.string.chk_credentials), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put(KEY_USERNAME, "");
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, username.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,     password.getText().toString().trim());
   //                params.put(KEY_GRANT_TYPE, grant_type);
   //                params.put(KEY_CLIENT_ID, client_id);
   //                params.put(KEY_CLIENT_SECRET, client_secret);

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + access_token);
            return headers;
        }




    };
    TwistedAppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_json_obj);
}
```

HOW TO OVERCOME THIS SERVER ERROR AND GET A RESPONSE

Comment: Your data makes no sense to the server, as explained in the error 422 description: "For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions." 

SOURCE: http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity

Answer (score 0):

got the same error. after long search i found this.
Add setRetryPolicy in your code

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
```